# mysql AND clause on same column multiple times

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve properties which has multiple amenities.

But the table structure is: properties are in `property` table and amenities are associated with the property.

Amenities table has:

```
id property_id amenity_name ....
```

Now i want to search the amenities that have 'parking' and 'elevator' and so on.

```
select property_id from amenities where name = 'parking' and name = 'elevator';
```

I dont want to fire a join query for this.

So can anybody save me in this situation?

Comment: select property_id from amenities where name = 'parking' and name = 'elevator'; will return nothing since name can't have both values at the same time. Can you detail a bit more on your table structure and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Moreover consider to accept some answer if you hope someone keeps on answering you. ;)

Comment: If you find an answer useful, accept it so that people will be reading your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -:

```
   scope :amenity_type, lambda {|term|
          where("amenities.name" => term).joins(:amenities).group("amenities.property_id").having("count(amenities.name) >= #{term.size}") unless term.blank?
   }
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
SELECT property_id FROM amenities
WHERE amenity_name IN ('parking', 'elevator')
GROUP BY property_id 
HAVING COUNT(amenity_name) >= 2
```

Here's what's going on...

First, get the list of Property ID's that have the amenities you're interested in:

`SELECT property_id FROM amenities WHERE amenity_name IN ('parking', 'elevator')`

Then narrow the list to include only those Property ID's which have more than one amenity. Grouping by property_id bundles the results into unique groups based on which property_id they belong to. Then, we simply count the number of amenity_names in each group and check if it's 2 or greater.

`GROUP BY property_id HAVING COUNT(amenity_name) >= 2`

One assumption in the code above is that you won't have the same amenity_name associated with a property_id more than once. To eliminate issues related to that, change the `HAVING` clause to include `DISTINCT` to weed out the duplicates, but don't add it unless you need it.

`GROUP BY property_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(amenity_name)) >= 2`

Comment: Saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
select property_id 
from amenities 
where name in ('parking','elevator')
group by property_id
having count(distinct(name)) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot nick ... This is working superbly :) . thanks a lot once again